# how to load mule-app.properties while writing MUnit

Tags: java, mule, munit

I am writing an MUnit and the port of HttpListerner is mentioned in mule-app.properties file. 
it is not getting loaded when i load the flow using getConfigResources.
is there anything else that I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one did the trick.

Set system property inside getConfigResources()

System.setProperty("http.port", "port_value");

Answer (score 0):

Try to load it using the Logger component, for example if you place the http listener configuration in mule-app.properties you may access it by this example xml configuration (also it is HttpListener not HttpListerner)

```
<logger message="${HttpListener}" level="INFO" doc:name="Log HttpListener Value"/>
```

your mule-app.properties file contains:

HttpListener="configuration example, url, host, port"

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to load the properties with the property-placeholder element in your Munit Flow, like this :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="mule-app.test.properties"/>
```

Event better would be to configure the properties needed for each flow I think, like this at the beginning of the Munit flow

```
<global-property name="prop1" value="value1"/>
<global-property name="prop2" value="value2"/>
```

You can then access them like normal property.

You can find the doc [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/configuring-properties)

Hope it helps.

/T

Comment: I am not suppose to change the flow.

Comment: I meant the Munit flow, in which you can do whatever you want, I suppose

Answer (score -1):

You can get the complete step by step solution to configure mule app-properties at
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/configuring-properties

Comment: Please expand this answer with the relevant parts from the link. It helps in case the link goes down, and for users searching for similar things.

Comment: i dont see an option to do it in the link provided. could you please explain?